# Disable a marker when is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to disable a marker when it is clicked so that the message is not repeated .
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Marker

I found this method  `setClickable` in another similar question but  it only makes the marker disappear, it doesn't disable it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      #map {
        height: 50%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatlng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Click to zoom'
        });


        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          var box = document.getElementById("box");
          var para = document.createElement("p");
          var node = document.createTextNode("Paragrap ")
          para.appendChild(node);
          box.appendChild(para);
        });

      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB_nzqNDBfJopGdzH2sNBbgHS-iotxkN_c&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejLJOg

Comment: What do you mean by "disable" the marker?

Comment: Like when you disable a button, and don't trigger a click event in javascript

Comment: So you want to remove/disable the click event listener?

Comment: yes but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#removing):

> **Removing Event Listeners**
>   To remove a specific event listener, it must have been assigned to a variable. You can then call removeListener(), passing the variable name to which the listener was assigned.
>
> var listener1 = marker.addListener('click', aFunction);
>      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);

Remove the listener in the eventListener callback function:

```
var listener = marker.addListener('click', function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode("Paragrap ")
  para.appendChild(node);
  box.appendChild(para);
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
});
```

**code snippet:**

```css
#map {
  height: 50%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var myLatlng = {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Click to zoom'
    });
    var listener = marker.addListener('click', function() {
      var box = document.getElementById("box");
      var para = document.createElement("p");
      var node = document.createTextNode("Paragrap ")
      para.appendChild(node);
      box.appendChild(para);
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```